# Update Progress is not working in Login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Update Progress in my Login page. Here when a user is clicking on btnLogin, it is validating the user and doing some database insertion and lastly redirecting to Home Page.
I am using the same Update progress in other pages in my project and its working fine but in this page it is not working.Please guide me that what mistake i am doing here.

```
 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Employee Quotient</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type" />
<link href="../Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        window.history.forward();
        function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
    } catch (err) { }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="noBack();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
    <form id="MyForm" method="post" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManger1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updLogin">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="header">
                    <div id="logo">
                        <div id="Div1">
                            <h1 style="color: White;">
                                EQ
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="topright">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="15px">
                                    <strong></strong>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserID" runat="server" ToolTip="Employee Code" Font-Names="Calibri"
                                        Font-Size="12px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TBWE2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtUserID"
                                        WatermarkCssClass="WaterMarkedTextBox" WatermarkText="ECode" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" ToolTip="Password"
                                        Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender1" runat="server"
                                        TargetControlID="txtPassword" WatermarkCssClass="WaterMarkedTextBoxPSW" WatermarkText="*" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" CssClass="buttonlogint" OnClick="btnLogin_Click"
                                        Text="Login" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" ForeColor="#6666FF" NavigateUrl="~/Account/ForgotPassword.aspx"
                                        Style="color: White; font-family: calibri; font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent;">Forgot Password</asp:HyperLink>
                                </td>
                                <td width="200px">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Password " ForeColor="White"
                                        Visible="false" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUserID"
                                        ErrorMessage="* UserID can't be left blank" Font-Bold="false" Style="display: none;
                                        font-family: Calibri" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
                                        ErrorMessage="* Password can't be left blank" Font-Bold="True" Style="display: none;" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="menulogin">
                </div>
                <div class="contentplaceholder">
                    <div id="single-column">
                        <h1>
                            &nbsp About EQ
                        </h1>
                        <p class="justify">
                            &nbsp Your partner in Productivity improvement.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="height: 515px;">
                        <h1>
                        </h1>
                        <p class="justify">
                            <strong>&nbsp &nbsp"</strong>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp *** More coming up here..keep
                            watching this space ***&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<strong>"</strong>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="footer">
                    <div id="footer-left">
                    </div>
                    <div id="footer-right">
                    </div>
                    <div id="footer-content">
                        <div id="footer-navigation">
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            Copyright &copy;  All rights reserved.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnLogin" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtUserID" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtPassword" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <div class="divTextAlign">
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgressForLogin" runat="server" DynamicLayout="true" associatedupdatepanelid="updLogin"
            >
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <table border="1px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="../images/faismall_logo.jpg" alt="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please define "is not working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManger1" 
                   runat="server" 
                   EnablePartialRendering="true" />
```

Instead of this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManger1" 
                   runat="server" 
                   EnablePartialRendering="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very much sure but please check the reference names and spells are ok

```
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgressForLogin" runat="server" DynamicLayout="true" associatedupdatepanelid="updLogin"
        >
```